# How to print multiple pdfs using pipe and stdin?

Tags: command-line, printing, lp, lpr

I am attempting to print multiple pdfs from the command line:

```
locate FilesIwantToPrint | grep pdf | lp -
```

This prints the list of pdfs on one page instead of printing the files themselves. Is it possible to achieve the latter behaviour?

Comment: Use `xargs lp` instead of `lp -`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What is `FilesIwantToPrint`? Show an example of the existing files and the pattern you use. The `xargs` solution might not work if you have file names that contain spaces or other special characters. I suggest to use `find` instead of `locate`, but I cannot propose a command without the missing details.

Comment: @Bodo most recent-ish versions of `locate` (including [plocate](https://plocate.sesse.net/) and [GNU locate](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Invoking-locate.html))have a `-0` or `--null` or similar option for NUL-separated output, which can be used with `xargs -0`.   e.g. `plocate -0 'FilesIwantToPrint' | grep -z pdf | xargs -0r lp`

Comment: More generally,  `locate`'s advantage over `find` is that it is fast because it doesn't have to recursively scan the filesystem or directory tree, it uses a cache of find's output at a particular point in time. The disadvantage is that it is, or can be, out of date. Any program relying on "cached" data from `locate` should be careful to check that each filename actually still exists before doing anything with it.

Comment: @cas some `locate` versions have `-e`/`--existing` flag (Print only entries that refer to files existing at the time `locate` is run.). Also instead of `grep` you can just use globbing (`FilesIwantToPrint*pdf`) or `--regex`.

Comment: @cas Without knowing what the OP actually uses instead of `FilesIwantToPrint` it is unclear if the speed advantage of `locate` is relevant, especially compared to the time for actually printing the documents. I assume it is very likely that the search can be limited to a specific base directory. Example: `find /path/to/directory -name '*FilesIwantToPrint*' -name '*pdf' -exec lp {} +` (The patterns `FilesIwantToPrint` and `pdf` can probably be combined.)

Comment: @aviro yeah, i initially used `plocate -0 --regex ...` in the example but changed it to use `grep -z` so it didn't differ too much from the OP's example.  @bodo possibly (indeed, quite likely), but without knowing for sure i'm reluctant to second-guess the OP's choice of tool. they might have some good reason for using locate that they haven't mentioned.